# Why is my bool property is not receiving a value using Get/Set in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, get, set

For some reason i can't seem to be able to change the value of the property `NoMoreWords` in the class `checkSpell` from within the class `manageWords` using `Get/Set`.

The full code is below but the important bit is here.

In `checkSpell` there is a bool property called `NoMoreWords` .
I then create an instance of the `checkSpell` object within `manageWords` and change the property `NoMoreWords`  to true. My watch window proves that the value has been changed in `manageWords`, but once i'm back in `checkSpell`, `NoMoreWords`  remains false.

Can you spot the problem and point me to the right direction? Thanks.

This is `checkSpell`

```
class checkSpell
{

    public bool finished = false;

    public bool NoMoreWords { get; set; }

    public void getWord()
    {

        manageWords mngit = new manageWords();
        speakIt spk = new speakIt();

        do
        {

            string word = mngit.readFile();     // Open the file and gets the word

            if (NoMoreWords == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NoMoreWords is TRUE");
                break;
            }

            //if (word == string.Empty) break;


            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Write the word: {0}", word.ToUpper());
            //spk.sayThis("Write the word: " + word);
            Console.Write(">");

            char[] a = word.ToCharArray(); //Converts string into chars

            getLetter(a); // METHOD



          //  if (finished == true) break;               

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);

            //spk.sayThis("Correct!");

            Console.WriteLine("");

        } while (!finished);

        Console.WriteLine("XXXX Bye Bye");
        spk.sayThis("Bye Bye");

    }


    /************************************************************************************************************************
     * Goes through the word (as a char[]) and compare with the typed letters                                               *
     ************************************************************************************************************************/

    public void getLetter(char[] a)
    {

        int b = 0;
        ConsoleKeyInfo k;
        ConsoleColor orig = Console.ForegroundColor;
        int CL = Console.CursorLeft;
        int CT = Console.CursorTop;
        string capOut = "";

        for (int i = b; i < a.Length; i = +b)
        {
            k = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                finished = true;
                break;
            }

            if (k.KeyChar == a[i])
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = orig;
                capOut = k.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();

                Console.Write(k.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper());
                b++;
                CL = Console.CursorLeft; //Get the cursor position of the last correct letter 
                CT = Console.CursorTop;

            }
            else if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {

                if (Console.CursorLeft > CL) Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, CT);
                ConsoleColor bg = Console.BackgroundColor;
                Console.ForegroundColor = bg;
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.CursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft - 1;

            }
            else if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                // i don't want to change line
            }

            else
            {

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write(k.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper());
                Console.ForegroundColor = orig;

            }

        }

    }
```

Now `manageWords`

```
 class manageWords // Check file, open and edit it
{

    public int lineNumber;

    //Check if file exists
    public string readFile()
    {

        string CurrentLine = "";
        int count = 0;

        checkSpell ckt = new checkSpell();

        try
        {


            START:

            count = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "words.txt")).Count(); // Gets number of lines

            var lines = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "words.txt"));

            if (lineNumber < count)
            {
                CurrentLine = lines.Skip(lineNumber).First();
                lineNumber++;
            }
            else 
            {
                ckt.NoMoreWords = true;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play it again? Yes/No: ");
                if (Console.ReadLine() == "yes")
                {
                    lineNumber = 0;
                    goto START;

                }
                else ckt.NoMoreWords = true;
            } 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            // Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return CurrentLine;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a smaller minimal reproduction of your problem that doesn't include so much code unrelated to replicating your problem?

Comment: What do you mean "once I'm back in checkSpell..." - are you in the same instance of checkSpell as the one that was just set?

Comment: @Servy Since i didn't know what was causing the problem, i thought that removing anything from the code could actually remove the possible cause. But i'll keep this in mind if i ask another question.

Comment: @Tim I meant it while debugging with Step Into and watching the value of the property.

Comment: @user3853326 That's why you need to actually run the program after removing superfluous code to make sure that it does indeed replicate the problem rather than just guessing.  Experiment.  Remove code, run program, see what happens.

Comment: @Servy I didn't think about that, Servy. As you can imagine i'm a beginner, but i'll do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because manageWords.readFile creates in own local checkSpell object (ckt), any changes to this local object will not affect the checkSpell object that calls manageWords.readFile. You should pass the caller into manageWords.readFile, e.g.,

```
public void getWord()
{
    manageWords mngit = new manageWords();
    speakIt spk = new speakIt();

    do
    {
        string word = mngit.readFile(this);     // pass local checkSpell
        // etc

class manageWords // Check file, open and edit it
{
    public int lineNumber;

    //Check if file exists
    public string readFile(checkSpell ckt)
    {
        string CurrentLine = "";
        int count = 0;
        // etc
```

You could also pass the checkSpell object into the manageWords constructor and store in a field in manageWords:

```
public void getWord()
{
    manageWords mngit = new manageWords(this);     // pass local checkSpell
    speakIt spk = new speakIt();

    do
    {
        string word = mngit.readFile();     // pass local checkSpell
        // etc

class manageWords // Check file, open and edit it
{
    public int lineNumber;
    private checkSpell ckt;

    public manageWords(checkSpell)
    {
        ckt = checkSpell;
    }

    //Check if file exists
    public string readFile()
    {
        // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is that you have two `checkSpell` instances in play.

- getWord method of `checkSpell` is an instance method, so it has access to the `NoMoreWords` property of *that* instance
- getWord constructs a new object of type `manageWords` and call `readFile`
- `manageWords.readFile` constructs another `checkSpell` instance, and it is *this* instance that gets `NoMoreWords` to be `true`

The original instance, the one you called `getWord` on, did not change.

Perhaps you should pass the original instance into the `readFile` method instead of having that method construct a new `checkSpell` object instance?

Basically alter your readFile method as follows:

```
public string readFile(checkSpell ckt)
```

And then pass in the checkSpell instance when calling readFile:

```
string word = mngit.readFile(this);
```

Also remember to remove the line in `readFile` that constructs the new `checkSpell` instance, you'll have to do that anyway since you can't have both a `ckt` parameter *and* a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is flawed.

You have `checkSpell` class creating an instance of `manageWords` and calling `manageWords.readFile()` from inside your `checkSpell.getWord()`. The problem is the fact that your `manageWords.readFile()` is creating a new instance of `checkSpell`.

It is never interacting with the instance you are looking at or expecting.

You can do the following as a quick hack and may be OK for your needs, but may not be valid for the structure of the entire program.

Change `manageWords.readFile()` to take in an instance of your `checkSpell` and use that instead of creating a new one.

```
public string readFile(checkSpell chkSpell)
{
    string CurrentLine = "";
    int count = 0;

    try
    {
        ....
        if (lineNumber < count)
        {
            CurrentLine = lines.Skip(lineNumber).First();
            lineNumber++;
        }
        else 
        {
            chkSpell.NoMoreWords = true;
            ....
        } 
        ....
    }
    ....
 }
```

Then from your `checkSpell.getWord()` call your `readFile()` like this: `mngit.readFile(this);`